# Concatenate Firebase DB calls

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase Cloud Function where I am having to get more data based on an ID provided, see code below:-

```
return admin.firestore().collection('companies').doc(snap.data().companyId).get().then((company) => {
    return admin.firestore().collection('customers').doc(snap.data().companyId).get().then((customer) => {
         console.log(company, customer);
    })
})
```

Is there a way I can combine these call so I don't have to make 2 calls to the DB every time I need to get the data?

This would help lower costs and help stop making expensive calls.

This example only has two levels of calls, some times this can go as far as three calls depending on what information I require from the DB inside my cloud function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't query two different collections at the same time.  You either have to perform multiple queries, or join your data ahead of time into a single collection to query that contains all the data.  This is called "denormalization", and is common in NoSQL databases that have no SQL-like join operations.