# Firestore - How to get posts that users likes using 3 roots collections?

Tags: javascript, database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve the posts liked by a user using 3 root collections, `users`, `posts`, `likes`.

I've structured my database like this :

```
users
 userId
  someData

posts
 postId
  someData
 postId
  someData
 postId
  someData

likes
 postId_userId
  someData
 postId_userId
  someData
```

So basically it's a users collection, a posts collection and a middle-man likes collection with a composite key as the ID.

I can't write likes in a post or a user document because it may have 100 or 10000 likes so not scaleable.

I think this method is too slow because I have to retrieve posts and then for each post I check if the relationship between the user and the post exists in the likes collection. So I have a filtered array of objects.

But It costs me a lot of reads... and seems messy.

Is there a more efficient way to do something like this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate Firebase DB calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52986554/concatenate-firebase-db-calls)

Comment: Not sure if this solves my problem, I canno't denormalize my data and store likes in the user or post object because I have no control no how many posts a user will like.

Comment: "I cannot denormalize my data" That's usually an unwise attitude when it comes to NoSQL data modeling. If you are complaining about the number of reads, duplicating data on writes is normally the only option. I get comfortable with this topic, I highly recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) and [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ)

Comment: Have you found a solution? Will it be helpful even if it implies a database schema change? Please reponde with @AlexMamo